# What does the +2 mean on my booked flight?

Tags: air-travel

Booked a flight from Manchester to Paris, France, that will then take me to Seoul, South Korea. The departing flight says

> 02 Oct 05:55 - 07:10 (+2) Manchester to Seoul 1x transfer (Paris)

Does the +2 mean I will only arrive in Seoul Tuesday at 7:10am? I have to be very certain since I will have someone picking me up at the airport and don't want to give them the wrong date!

Comment: Please provide the airline names, flight numbers, and departure dates for both the Manchester > Paris flight and the Paris > Seoul flight.

Comment: Should we assume MAN and not MHT, since MHT doesn't seem to be an international airport?

Comment: Does your flight go directly MAN-CDG (and CDG-ICN), or does it go MAN-AMS-CDG (and then CDG-ICN)? I see a 40h and a 45h flight MAN-AMS (14h layover), AMS-CDG (11h layover), CDG-ICN that leaves at 1635 on Sunday and arrives 1635 on Tuesday.

Comment: Very, very closely related (possibly duplicate?) question which also answers this one: [What does the (+1) mean in flight search engines?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/20116/12011)

Answer (score 37):

In general, +2 would mean that the flight arrives 2 days after departure.  This is not uncommon especially when you're crossing the international date line where you lose a day whilst in flight.  eg, flights from San Francisco to Australia always land "2 days" after they depart - despite only being a ~15 hour flight.

However, that itinerary does not cross the international date line, so the +2 is odd.

The flights that correspond to the times you've mentioned are AF1269 (MAN-CDG) and AF264 (CDG-ICN). Normally, there would be a ~4 hour gap between the first of those flights landing and the second departing, and you would arrive in ICN on the day after departure (ie, +1)

It is possible that you actually have booked flights that give a ~28 hour layover in Paris (which would result in a +2 day arrival), however in this case that does not appear to be possible as AF264 does not fly on the 3rd of October, and there are no other flights that arrive in Seoul at 7:10am.

Most likely wherever you are seeing the details showing as +2 is thus incorrect, and you actually arrive in Seoul on the Monday the 3rd of October. However I would be checking with the airline to make sure of that!

Comment: "flights from San Francisco to Australia always land '2 days' after they depart - despite only being a ~15 hour flight." (And the return leg, they land *before* take off.)

Comment: Yeah, +2 is very common for flights from the U.S. to either Australia or Asia if they leave before midnight. If they leave after midnight, though, then they're usually just +1.

Answer (score 5):

> What does the +2 mean on my booked flight?

It means that the arrival time is two days later (local time). One can double check by looking at flight and layover durations as well as timezone changes. A few years ago, Qatar Airways mentioned +1 on one of my tickets while in fact it was +2.

Comment: Yeah I'm curious what it says his Paris layover time is. That could explain why it's +2.